# Client / Server socket programming with ipv6 in java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, ipv6, wifi-direct

I'm trying to connect two devices through wifi direct ,and then transfer the data between them by the socket.

in the Serve side I have this code

```
  ArrayList<SendReceive> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
public class ServerClass extends Thread{
    
      ServerSocket server;
      {
          try {
              server = new ServerSocket(8888, 5);

          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      public void run() {
          while (true) {
              try {
                  Socket client =server.accept();
                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          appendStatus("Connection from " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                      }
                  });
                  SendReceive serverThread=new SendReceive(client);
                  threadList.add(serverThread);
                  serverThread.start();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  System.out.println("Error occured in main: " + e.getStackTrace());
              }
          }
      }
     
  }
```

and on the Client side I have this code

```
 public class ClientClass extends Thread{
        Socket socket;
        String hostAdd;
        public ClientClass(InetAddress hostAddress){
            hostAdd=hostAddress.getHostAddress();

            socket=new Socket();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAdd,8888),500);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        CONSt.setText("now the client connected to server.");
                    }
                });
                sendReceive=new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note : the code of SendReceive is

```
private class SendReceive extends Thread{
        private Socket socket;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private OutputStream outputStream;
        public SendReceive(Socket skt){
            socket=skt;
            try {
                inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
                outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer =new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            while (socket!=null){
                try {
                    bytes=inputStream.read(buffer);
                    if(bytes>0){
                        String tempMsg=new String(buffer,0,bytes);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                appendStatus(tempMsg);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        public void write(byte[] bytes){
            try {
                outputStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

this work with ipv4 adress like

```
ClientClass clientClass= new ClientClass( InetAddress.getByName("192.168.49.1"));
  clientClass.start();
```

but doesn't work on ipv6 address like

```
 ClientClass clientClass= new ClientClass( InetAddress.getByName("fe80::58a2:b5ff:fe7f:ea51%p2p0"));
  clientClass.start();
```

**I need to work with ipv6 , what's the problem!! why this code doesn't work with ipv6 and work with ipv4 , how I make it work with ipv6 .**

I will appreciate any answer

Comment: What type of IPv6 address (Global, ULA, Link-Local) are you trying to use? With Link-Local IPv6 addresses, you need to also use a Zone ID.

Comment: yeah is link local ipv6 because as you see is start with fe80 , pleas tell me what the code I must use , how I use Zone ID

Comment: The Zone ID is an OS-specific representation of the intended interface, and it is required for IPv6 link-local addressing because all interfaces in a host use the same link-local network, so you need it to determine which interface is meant. See: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4007#section-11

Comment: because I work on wifi direct ,I use p2p-interface as we see here ("fe80::58a2:b5ff:fe7f:ea51%p2p0") , so the Zone ID is (%p2p0) Right ?!

Comment: I have no idea what OS you have, or what the Zone ID for your interface would be. Windows uses an interface number, e.g. `%2`, and different versions of Linux use different representations.

Comment: I'm working on android phones , and by using this code `for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                appendStatus("interface: "+" "+intf.getName());
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();){
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();}}` I get the interface and its addresses , like (interface p2p0  with ipv4:192.168.49.1 and ipv6:fe80::58a2:b5ff:fe7f:ea51%p2p0)